# Laravel/Eloquent and comparing dates

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to return all of the rows in my database table that are a day or less old.  I'm using Laravel 4.  This is what I tried:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
return MainContact::where(DATEDIFF('timestamp', $date), '<=', 1)->get();
```

This doesn't work.  I read the documentation and it doesn't seem like you can pass Laravel MySQL functions.  `timestamp` is a datetime field.  How can I compare these dates in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer that user1977808 gave you is not good because MySQL can't use an index on the timestamp column, since it has to compute an output of the DATE_SUB function for every row. Avoid such queries, they have to process the entire table every time!

How about something like this:

```
return MainContact::where('timestamp', '>=', time() - (24*60*60))->get();
```

I put the `>=` in there because you said "a day or less old", so they must have timestamp that is later than yesterday.

Comment: Yeah, I had to adjust his MySQL.

Comment: I did `MainContact::where('timestamp', '>', DB::raw('NOW() - INTERVAL ' . $interval . ' DAY')->get();` and then passed in the interval I wanted.

Comment: You can also use `strtotime("-1 day")`, like this:
`MainContact::where('timestamp', '>' strtotime("-{$interval} day"))->get();`

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively,

You can use [Carbon API](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) that bundle with Laravel.

```
ModelName::where( 'timestamp', '>=', Carbon::now() )->get();
```

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators

Comment: He is using Laravel 4 not 5.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `whereDate()`, `whereDay()`, `whereMonth()` and `whereYear()`. In this case, `whereDate()` could be used as such, with Carbon's easy date functions:

`return MainContact::whereDate('dateField', '<', Carbon::now()->subDay())->get();`

Answer (score 2):

```
return MainContact::where('timestamp', '>=', time() - (24*60*60))->get();
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a raw query by using:

```
$results = DB::query( 'query' );
```

You only don't the the model object back in the results var

Comment: I was hoping there was a better way.